Can't set shutter speed longer than 1/48s on Sony a7c II
I have sony a7c camera. I switched to manual mode. I have 3 dials, for aperture, shutter speed and iso. I can change ISO and Aperture to any level I want, but shutter speed never goes longer than 1/48s. No matter what I do I scroll further it always stays at 1/48s.
In custom c1 mode, I can increase shutter speed to 4" by closing aperture to f16. But 1 dial always change both settings together, making exposure to 0.

I am in manual mode
I have mechanical shutter enabled (silent mode disabled).
I tried to play with bulb settings
I tried to turned off stabilization, but it doesn't get me any effect


A screenshot of your backscreen would be nice, so that we can actually see the settings you are in. Otherwise we have to take your word, you are not making a mistake with what you say you do.

Also you might want to check if you accidently set a minimum shutter speed: https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/2020/v1/en/contents/TP1000139958.html - I think this would only be active in the program modes, but checking is surely worth the effort.

@KaiMattern, Auto ISO (and the min SS setting) can be active while in manual mode... I think this is the issue.

Are you sure the camera is set to take still images, rather than 30 or 24 fps video?

Finally found:

Menu
Shooting
Shutter/silent
Anti-flicket Set.
Var.Shutter -> turned that to Off.


Thanks for sharing! I never saw that setting before.

If you were in full manual mode, then this would indicate a problem with the electronics of your camera. Hoever, I believe, that is not the case.
You can set the mode to manual and still have auto iso enabled. This is actually a pretty convenient mode as you then have the advantages of almost full control while still using the advantage of the automatic exposure.
As this can create situations where you can comfortably take photos with very odd settings like using a very high shutter speed in a dark environment, you can set limits to ISO and shutter speed.
These hard limits however can of course lead to situations where the camera appears to stubbornly refuse going into these limits.
The function in your camera's setting is labeled: ISO AUTO Min. SS
In custom mode, the camera would also apply other settings, so it could be that you set the custom mode profile before you set a restriction on the main profile.
See here: helpguide.sony.net/ilc/2020/v1/en/contents/TP1000139958.html
Also please check that you are in a still image mode. 1/48sec sounds more like a movie setting.

I could be mistaken, but I think 1/48 is the longest exposure time allowed when shooting 24 fps. But I'm not a video guy and I don't shoot Sony.
